# es6 class - pass boolean to constructor

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, boolean, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get to grips with es6 classes and I seem to be unable to pass a boolean value to a constructor.

In the following code

```
export default class site_alert {
  constructor(options) {
    this.message = options.message || 'default cookie message';
    this.autoDisplay = options.autoDisplay || true;
    console.log(this.autoDisplay);
  }
}

var sitemessage = new site_alert({
  message:"Some string",
  autoDisplay: false
});
```

`autoDisplay` is always `true`, it takes the default value regardless of whats being passed to it when I create an instance of the class.

If I change `autoDisplay` to be a string it works fine.

Are you unable to pass booleans to the constructor like this?

Comment: That's because `||` is an or comparator. You've effectively said `options.autoDisplay OR true`, which always resolves to `true`, regardless of `options.autoDisplay` value.

Comment: Even if you pass the value as false, it will end up in the constructor as: this.autoDisplay = false || true, which is indeed true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`false || true` is always `true`. `||` is evaluated like this:

- Evaluate the left-hand side
- If the left-hand side is *truthy*, that's the result
- Otherwise, evaluate the right-hand side and make that the reslt

So `||` isn't the way to do this. You'd also have trouble if you wanted to be able to supply any other falsy value, like `0`, `""`, `null`, etc.

You *could* use `typeof options.autoDisplay === "undefined"` or `"autoDisplay" in options` (more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411352/how-best-to-determine-if-an-argument-is-not-sent-to-the-javascript-function?lq=1) and its answers)

```
this.autoDisplay = typeof options.autoDisplay === "undefined" ? true : options.autoDisplay;
```

...but you're using ES2015 ("ES6"), so you can avoid all that boilerplate by using *default arguments* and *argument destructuring*:

```
constructor({message = 'default cookie message', autoDisplay = true} = {}) {
    this.message = message;
    this.autoDisplay = autoDisplay;
    console.log(this.message, "|", this.autoDisplay);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class site_alert {
  constructor({message = 'default cookie message', autoDisplay = true} = {}) {
    this.message = message;
    this.autoDisplay = autoDisplay;
    console.log(this.message, "|", this.autoDisplay);
  }
}
new site_alert();
new site_alert({autoDisplay:false});
new site_alert({message:"custom message"});
```

Note how in our function code, we don't even have `options` anymore; the arguments are destructured from the options object for us when the function is called.

Let's look at that declaration:

```
{message = 'default cookie message', autoDisplay = true} = {}
```

The `{message = 'default cookie message', autoDisplay = true}` part says:

- The first (only, in our case) argument will be an object we want destructured (thanks to the `{}` around it)
- If there's no `message` property on it, default to 'default cookie message'
- If there's no 'autoDisplay' property on it, default to true

...and the `= {}` part says: If the argument isn't given, default to a blank object (after which the two defaults above will kick in).

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions (classes) are written with a capital first letter (and usually in CappedCamelCase), so `SiteAlert` rather than `site_alert`. You don't have to follow convention, but just flagging it up if you didn't know.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for the detailed reply. Thats really helpful :D